# Division automorphism

Tags: terminology, division-algebras, morphism

Let S be a set and A be a set of automorphisms of S such

$\forall\ x,y\in S, \exists!\ a\in A \ |\ ax=y$

What's the name of this structure/property, that's similar to a "division algebra" using morphisms?

Comment: Do you mean for every $x,y\in S$ there exists a unique $a\in A$ such that $ax=y$?

Comment: If $A$ is a group, people usually say in this case  that the action of $A$ on $S$ is **free**. If $A$ is just a set, I do not know how it is called.

Comment: @JCAA free and transitive.

Comment: Yes, and transitive.

Comment: So if $A$ is a group, then either $S$ is the emptyset and $A$ is the trivial group, or we can identify $S=A$, with the regular action of $A$ on itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $S$ is not empty then this structure is a Latin square: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square

The elements of $A$ are the symbols and we have a map $S \times S \to A$, sending $(x,y)$ to the unique $a\in A$ which maps $x\mapsto y$.

Comment: If $S$ non-empty then there must exist bijections $S\to A$ (e.g. fix $x\in S$ and map $y\in S$ to the unique $a\in A$ such that $ax=y$).  If you pick a bijection and add it to your structure, then you get a quasigroup.   Note Latin squares up to equivalence, are maps $S\times T \to A$, where there exist bijections between $S,T,A$, whereas your structure is equipped with a bijection $S\to T$.  Thus there is only one Latin square up to equivalence on $S=\{1,2,3\}$ but two of your structure: $A=\{(),(123),(321)\}$ and $A=\{(12),(23),(31)\}$.